# How to compute an int from a recursive method in Dart?

Tags: dart, recursion, integer

I want to compute the depth of a recursive object in Dart (kind of tree). Root node has a `null` as its parent.

```
class MyNode {
  MyNode? parent;
  int get depth => 1 + ((parent == null) ? -1 : parent.depth);
  }
```

This code should return 0 for the root node, 1 for roots children and so on. But it does not compile due to error

```
A value of type 'double' can't be returned from the function 'depth' because it has a return type of 'int'.
```

How to rewrite method `depth` to work as expected?

Dart version is 3.1.3

Comment: A more direct version, without the `-1`, could be `int get depth => switch (parent) { var p? => p.depth + 1, _ => 0 };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the error message you are getting since that does not seems right. But the error message you should get are the following on your `parent.depth` call:

```dart
class MyNode {
  MyNode? parent;
  int get depth => 1 + ((parent == null) ? -1 : parent.depth);
  // The property 'depth' can't be unconditionally accessed
  // because the receiver can be 'null'.
}
```

Reason being that even if you have checked if `parent` might be `null`, in theory you could have replaced this variable with a getter in a subclass which does not return the same value every time you request the value.

Instead, I suggest rewrite the code to the following:

```dart
class MyNode {
  MyNode? parent;
  int get depth => 1 + (parent?.depth ?? -1);
}
```

Here we make use of two null-aware operators, `?.` and `??`:

- `parent?.depth` means that if `parent` is `null`, we will just return `null`. If `parent` is not `null`, we return the value of calling `parent.depth`.
- `??` means that if the left-side are `null`, we use the value to the right. Otherwise, we use the value to the left.

So `parent?.depth ?? -1` ends up meaning that if `parent` are `null`, we use the `-1` value. Otherwise, we use the value of `parent.depth`. And all of this can be done without ending up asking `parent` twice about it being `null` and it is therefore safe to do so.

Comment: Hi. First: I used a ternary operator. Within this operator "parent" cannot become "null". Second: Both your and my approach should lead to the same result. Third: unfortunately both your and my approach lead to the same error: "A value of type 'double' can't be returned from the function 'depth' because it has a return type of 'int'.

Comment: Answer accepted as solution. I have above code in a mixin and Dart produced this misleading error. Solution was proper casting. Discussion with you lead to the solution. Thx